# I want to return an array from the user defined function myibnr. I'm having problems returning the array

Tags: arrays, r, function

```
d_date <- "23-10-2015"
mypreibnr(d_date)
```

And myibnr returns yq only. 
The above code gives me the output

```
"2015-16 Q3"
```

I've presented the code below for a range of rows.  I get an error highlighting the paste0 rows in the function myibnr.

I'm returning the financial year for a given date.  ibnr_data[,7] is the required date column and ibnr_data[i,8] is the required output column.

```
i=1
while(i<=nrow(ibnr_data)){
d_date <- ibnr_data[i,7] 
mypreibnr(d_date)
i <- i+1
} 

mypreibnr <- function(d_temp){
temp <- dmy(d_temp) # passed as t in myibnr(a,t)
b    <- substr(year(temp),4,4)
myibnr(b,temp)

myibnr  <- function(a, t){
temp1 <- dmy(str_replace("01-04-201x","x",a))
temp2 <- dmy(str_replace("30-06-201x","x",a))
temp3 <- dmy(str_replace("01-07-201x","x",a))
temp4 <- dmy(str_replace("30-09-201x","x",a))
temp5 <- dmy(str_replace("01-10-201x","x",a))
temp6 <- dmy(str_replace("31-12-201x","x",a))
temp7 <- dmy(str_replace("01-01-201x","x",a))
temp8 <- dmy(str_replace("31-03-201x","x",a))
yyy   <- substr(t,1,3)
ay    <- as.numeric(a)
ay_0  <- ay-1
ay_1  <- ay+1
qt    <-    which(unlist(list(between(t,temp1,temp2),between(t,temp3,temp4),between(t,temp5,temp6),between(t,temp7,temp8))))
if(qt<=3){
  yq  <- paste0(yyy,ay,"-",yyy,ay_1," Q",qt,sep="")
  } else {
  yq  <- paste0(yyy,ay_0,"-",yyy,ay," Q",qt,sep="")
  }
  ibnr_data[i,8] <- yq
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provide a small reproducible example and expected output based on that.

Comment: It's also good practice to include any packages you are using; in this case `stringr` and `dplyr` or `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems with your code:

1. You never closed the first function, `mypreibnr`; add a `}`.
2. Though this is technique/style only, your indentation is inconsistent and non-standard; consider using RStudio, ESS, or something else that automates indentation for you. This would likely have helped with #1.
3. You incorrectly assume that your last line, `ibnr_data[i,8] <- yq` will know to return **all** of `ibnr_data`.

For the last (the culprit), realize that assignment to a variable in *R* invisibly returns the value actually assigned. This allows *chaining* of assignment, so that

```
x <- y <- 5
```

assigns the value 5 to both `x` and `y`. This is equivalent to

```
x <- (y <- 5)
```

highlighting the fact that the assignment of 5 to `y` is done first, it silently returns a 5, which is then assigned to `x` (and invisibly returned). If you apply this logic to your code, you will see that

```
obnr_data[i,8] <- yq
```

is assigning the value of `yq` (a single string) to a member of the vector `ibnr_data`. So it is the single string (`yq`) that is invisibly returned by the assignment, *not the contents of the entire vector*. (Had you made an assignment of a vector of strings, then that would have been invisibly returned.)

Perhaps adding `ibnr_data` after the assignment will do what you need?